# Some questions about security in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a number of security concerns about my current application and wondering if I am leaving myself open to abuse, in the following arenas.

a) .My main access control method is by maining a current_user, current_company current_project method in my application controller.  These methods return object based on stored session keys established when a user logs in and cleared when they log out.  I.e if I want to know something about the current user, I can call "current_user.role" or if I want see whether the account a user is trying to change belongs to him, I check whether the associated account id which is requested in the url actually belongs to that user, essentially as follows

in Account controller

```
def account_info
  redirect_to login_path if !user.logged_in
  account_id=params[:account_id]
  @account = Account.find(account_id)
  unless account_belongs_to_user(account_id)
    redirect_to unauthorized_path
  end
```

end

In my application controller, when a user is initially authenticated, I do something like this:

```
session[:current_user_id] = user.id
```

and clear that session key when the user logs out.

Then when account is requested, and account_belongs_to_user is called, the application controller processes it, more or less like this:

```
def account_belongs_to_user(account_id)
  account = Account.find(account_id)
  return account.user_id==session[:current_user_id]
end
```

So I guess my security scheme ultimately relies on whether the session data is secure and not trivially spoofable.

b) When I render pages I sometimes pass objects which have senstive data to my erb pages to generate the page text.

For example, I might pass a "company" object (ActiveRecord) to the view to generate an invoice screen.  But the company object, passed as @company, has a lot of sensitive data like access keys and the like.  Not really being fully aware of the the internals, if I don't specifically include something like:

```
<%= @company.access_token %>
```

on my web page, can I be confident that the attributes of @company won't somehow be passed into the browser unless I specifically ask for them to be rendered on the page?

This is obviously an issue when using rails to serve data for say, AngularJS single page applications, as everything I pass for Angular to render the page I assume is probably accessible to an evil-doer even if not on the page itself, but I'm hoping that's not the case with pages generated server side by rails.

This may be a naive question, but thanks as I just want to be certain what I am doing before start spilling secrets all over the place.

Comment: Well to start with don't reinvent the wheel. Home rolled authentication solutions are a leading cause of security breaches. Even if they are actually done properly (which is rare) they are seldom maintained to address vulnerabilities. You also want to seperate authentication which is concerned with the identity of the the user from authorization which is concerned with who gets to do what.

Comment: I agree on the first part, and I'm using a standard gem for user authentication, but am trying to address the "who gets to do what" question.  I need to make sure that a request by an authenticated user typing in URLs (e.g. myapp/account/show?12) owns the resource they requested

Comment: Have you looked at the cancancan gem? It solves this very issue in a maintainable, easily reviewable and secure way.

Comment: I would go with Pundit for authorization. CanCanCan is somewhat easier at first but the whole DSL just gets in the way later when you need to deal with more complicated scenarios while Pundit is just plain OOP. The fact that all your authorization logic gets crammed into a single file in CanCanCan is also not very maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions, although I wonder whether it is worth the trouble of to add in an entire authorizaiton platform given that the only thing I need to do is check whether the current user the owner of the resource which he/she is requesting. That is fairly easily confirmed, assuming I can rely on the session key plumbing built into rails is not trivailly spoofed.    Leaving aside for the moment the wisdom of "rolling your own" anything, is there an obvious security issue with the solution described above?

Answer (score 0):

put an authentication for the token using active_record callback
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say "authentication for the token"?